# How React Redux Reselect manages previous arguments?

Tags: reactjs, redux

How does [React Redux Reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect/blob/master/src/index.js) manages the previous arguments and where and that will be compared with the current arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the previous arguments are encapsulated within their own memoization code. If you need to access a previous state of your application, it may be worthwhile looking into a separate middleware like this: https://github.com/omnidan/redux-undo